# How to I call a three js function within node js

Tags: node.js, function, express

I experiment with node js, express and three js.

I have the following files:

index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/js/client_world.js', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/js/client_world.js');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("A user is connected");

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("User disconnected");
    });
}); 

http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Listenng to port 8080")
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="//threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/client_world.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
<script>    
        var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function(){
        loadWorld();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and js/client_world.js:

```
var container, scene, camera, renderer, cube;   

var loadWorld = function(){

    //Setup------------------------------------------
    container = document.getElementById('container');

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

        camera.position.y = -400;
        camera.position.z = 400;
        camera.rotation.x = .70;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

        cube.rotation.z = .75

        scene.add(cube);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        //Final touches-----------------------------------
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

};
```

It works like this.
How can I call the function loadWorld() without using socket? I would like to integrate this part in a program where the port 8080 can not be used for the socket.

Thanks for a support.

I try to explain what I want to do: I have a website with 2 links. The first leads to a page displaying data from a database. Here you can enter data and save it to the database. The second link should open a page with a graphical presentation. This site uses three js. Now I am looking for a way to display the three js graphic within node js with express and pug. The example above, only the display with three js works. But I can not build it into the project with the database like that.

```
const express = require('express');
const seiten = require('./seiten.json');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const movieRouter = require('./movie');
const model = require('./movie/model');
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

const app = express();

......
......


......
const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
console.log("Listenng to port 8080")
});
```

This will give me the error: Adress already in use 8080.
My question about it: How can I call the function loadWorld() without using socket?

In the meantime I tried the following:

I call profile.pug

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title Graphische Darstellung
body

    block content

    div.container
    script(src='/three.min.js')
    script(src='/client_world.js')
```

mit:

```
....
....
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {

model.getAll().then(
movies => {
  res.render('profile', {movies} );
},
error => res.send(error),
);

});

......
......
```

but only a blank page is displayed.

Comment: Why would you want to? The server side doesn't have a document. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "client_world is" a child website with three js. I'm looking for a possibility to to embed three js in node js. Everything I found on the net is the example above.

Comment: If you render on the server side, what then? Are you asking how to create an image in NodeJS and send the resulting image to a client?

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
var app = express()
, server = require('http').createServer(app)
, io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(8080, function(){
console.log("Listenng to port 8080")
});
```

Both, the app and the socket.io server, run on the same port.